# Why ${a}^{\frac 1n}$ $ (a\in \Bbb{R},n\in \Bbb{N}, n\ge2)$ should be undefined unless $a\gt0$?

Tags: definition, exponentiation, real-numbers

In the most recent national mathematics textbook for 10th grade in my home country, 
 ${a}^{\frac 1n}$ is defined in the following way:

> For every natural number $n \ge2$, positive number $a$ raised to power of ${\frac 1n}$ is defined as: $${a}^{\frac 1n} = \sqrt[n]a$$

($a \in \Bbb{R}$ as stated before definition)

and then adds:

> Throught this book if $a\lt0$, ${a}^{\frac 1n}$ is not defined. For example expressions such as ${(-1)}^{\frac 13}$ and ${(-2)}^{\frac 24}$ are undefined.

(Definition and comment above can be seen on page 65 of the pdf version available through the following link (Persian)(PDF): http://chap.sch.ir/sites/default/files/lbooks/96-97/40/C110211.pdf)

What is the reason of defining it this way?

Comment: It's worth noting that Wolfram|Alpha will output a non-real answer for things like $(-1)^{1/3}$, but a real answer when you ask for the cube root.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, the students do not learn about the complex numbers. As a result, there is no meaningful definition for things like $(-1)^{\frac12}$, which under any reasonable definition should be something that, when squared, gives $-1$; but such a number does not exist within the real numbers.

In case $n$ is odd, there is of course a good definition as a negative number, but for simplicity they presumably just decide to restrict radicals to positive numbers, no matter which radical.

Comment: And above all, even if they know about complex numbers (which they learn towards the end of high-school), how can they  decide which  root is $(-1)^{\tfrac12}$? For (positive) real numbers, there's no problem: people agree to say it's the non-negative square root. One can't set tsuch a convention for complex numbers.

Comment: Well, you *can*; e.g., you decide to take the complex number with the smallest argument (angle from the positive real axis). That is a perfectly good definition. Of course, your rules don't work as nicely anymore; $1 = 1^{1/2} = (-1 \times -1)^{1/2} \neq (-1)^{1/2}\times (-1)^{1/2} = -1$.

Comment: Precisely. That's the problem.: it is useless to introduce new symbolic notations if you have no sensible computation rules.

Answer (score 0):

That is for two reasons:

First, $a^x$, for $x\in \mathbf R$ is defined as $\;\mathrm e^{x\ln a}$, and $$\ln a$ is defined for $a>0$.

Second, while we may very well speak of $\;\sqrt[3]{\mathstrut -8}$, for instance, the exponential notation $(-8)^{\tfrac13}$ leads to inconsistencies:
\begin{align}(-8)^{\tfrac13}&=(-8)^{\tfrac26}=\bigl((-8)^2\bigr)^{\tfrac16}=(64)^{\tfrac16}=2,\\
\text{but}\qquad
(-8)^{\tfrac13}&=\Bigl((-8)^{\tfrac16}\Bigr)^2\qquad\text{is not defined!}
\end{align}